# Cannot initialize context because there is already a root application context present (using annotations only)

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-security

When i try to deploy my application on Tomcat, i receive error shown below:

```
    23-Dec-2016 20:46:56.516 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1]         org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending      context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot initialize context because there is already a root application context present - check whether you have multiple ContextLoader* definitions in your web.xml!
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:297)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5189)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1702)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:431)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:324)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

23-Dec-2016 20:46:56.523 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
23-Dec-2016 20:46:56.525 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
```

The main problem is that I don't have any web.xml files and i don't see any additional ContextLoaders. 
I am using only annotations. I can't figure out why this exception occur and how to fix it. When I start application using @SpringBootApplication annotation, everything works correctly.

**BackendWebAppInitializer:**

```
package com.inyourhead.backend;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

@SuppressWarnings("javadoc")
public class BackendWebAppInitializer
    extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer
{

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses()
    {
        return new Class[] { RootConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses()
    {
        return new Class[] { WebConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings()
    {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }
}
```

**RootConfig:**

```
package com.inyourhead.backend;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@SuppressWarnings("javadoc")
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(
    basePackages = { "com.inyourhead.backend.configuration",
        "com.inyourhead.backend.data" })
public class RootConfig
{

}
```

**WebConfig:**

```
package com.inyourhead.backend;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@SuppressWarnings("javadoc")
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.inyourhead.backend.web" })
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
{

}
```

**SecurityConfig:**

```
package com.inyourhead.backend.configuration.security;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

/**
 * Created by aleksander on 28.11.16.
 */
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {


        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
                .usersByUsernameQuery("select u.login, u.haslo, true from uzytkownik u where u.login=?")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select u.login, u.typ from uzytkownik u where u.login=?");
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable()

                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/search.*", "/home", "/register.*")
                .permitAll().and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login").authenticated()
                .and().httpBasic();
        }


    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return encoder;
    }

}
```

**TokenFilter:**

```
package com.inyourhead.backend.configuration.security.filters;

import com.inyourhead.backend.other.JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

/**
 * Created by aleksander on 30.11.16.
 */
@Configuration
public class TokenFilter {
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean jwtRegistrationBean() throws Exception {
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        registrationBean.setFilter(authenticationTokenFilterBean());
        registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/store","/store/**", "/logout");
        return registrationBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter authenticationTokenFilterBean() throws Exception {
        return new JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter();
    }
}
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.inyourhead</groupId>
    <artifactId>backend</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>Backend</name>
    <description>Backend application</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <snippetsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-snippets</snippetsDirectory>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- token dependency-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.193</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.inyourhead.backend.BackendApplication</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
                <artifactId>asciidoctor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-docs</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process-asciidoc</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirectory>src/main/resources/asciidoc</sourceDirectory>
                            <backend>html</backend>
                            <doctype>book</doctype>
                            <attributes>
                                <snippets>${snippetsDirectory}</snippets>
                            </attributes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: You are using Spring Boot which already registers all the stuff for you. Remove your `BackendWebAppInitializer`. You don't need it because you are using Spring Boot, either use it or don't.

Comment: If you have a web.xml file, as was our case, this solutions worked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8492173/cannot-initialize-context-because-there-is-already-a-root-application-context-pr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure where did you get the base class for `BackendWebAppInitializer` but for traditional WAR deployments you should follow this [guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html) on which it is explained that you need to provide a class that extends `SpringBootServletInitializer`. Something like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Configure your pom to package as `war` and use the `spring-boot-maven-plugin`. You also gotta turn the `provided` scope on for `spring-boot-starter-tomcat`.

Comment: Hi Ulises, I have followed the guide but still facing the same issue. Any suggestions ? I have only api and authentication manager in my project and WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter